# SyntaxError: missing ; before statement Json array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Excuse the n00b

I have this simple json jquery call that i am having issues with.

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var table = $('#datatable');
        $.ajax({          
        type:  'GET',
     url:   'http://jsonurl',
        dataType: 'jsonp',              
        success: function(data) {
                    $.each(data.responseData.leaderboard, function(i, item){
                        var rowItem = '<tr><td>' + item.userid +
                                      '</td><td>' + item.username + 
                                      '</td><td>' + item.companyname +
                                      '</td/></tr>';

                        table.append(rowItem);
                        return i<4;
                    });

                }
        });

    });
</script>
```

the json url returns a result like such

```
{"status": "success",
 "message": "",
 "responseData": {
     "leaderboard": [
         {
             "userid": 1,
             "username": "username1",
             "companyname": "Working com 1",
             "currentlevel": 1
         },
         {
             "userid": 2,
             "username": "username2",
             "companyname": "Working com 1",
             "currentlevel": 13
         }
     ]
 }
}
```

when i try with a structure that is not in an array the code works but with above i get a SyntaxError: missing ; before statement error in firebug console. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: in which line do u get the error?

Comment: Its working fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/0m6x13fn/

Comment: says line 1 on  

{"status":"success","message":"","responseData":{"leaderboard":[{"use says in between "status" and "success"

Comment: have you checked out the fiddle above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to duplicate the error by omitting the variable assignment as shown below.

It would be helpful if you would explain this part of your question ...

> when i try with a structure that is not in an array the code works but
>   with above i get a SyntaxError: missing ;

**This example will return** *SyntaxError: missing ; before statement*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// var data = 
{"status": "success",
 "message": "",
 "responseData": {
     "leaderboard": [
         {
             "userid": 1,
             "username": "username1",
             "companyname": "Working com 1",
             "currentlevel": 1
         },
         {
             "userid": 2,
             "username": "username2",
             "companyname": "Working com 1",
             "currentlevel": 13
         }
     ]
 }
}

</script>
```

**This example works without an error:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var data = 

{"status": "success",
 "message": "",
 "responseData": {
     "leaderboard": [
         {
             "userid": 1,
             "username": "username1",
             "companyname": "Working com 1",
             "currentlevel": 1
         },
         {
             "userid": 2,
             "username": "username2",
             "companyname": "Working com 1",
             "currentlevel": 13
         }
     ]
 }
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `dataType: 'jsonp'` to `dataType: 'json'`

The data you are receiving is `json` not `jsonp`. Thus, the error has occured.

Comment: Good spot Akash. This is the correct answer as I just tested it. However, to actually see the error I had to add an error function to the jQuery ajax call.  Without it, the ajax call failed silently in the debugger.

Comment: Thanks Akash, you are right the data was coming in as a json. Good spot